# EF The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime

I Have read more similar questions as this...

I have created a BD but after to creation I thought to add a `DateTime` field to save the datetime registration, but when I type update-database (after creation the migration), the Package Manager Console show me the error of the title

I already tried this:

```
AlterColumn("dbo.Dispositivoes", "RegisterDate", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "GETDATE()"));
AlterColumn("dbo.Dispositivoes", "RegisterDate", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false, defaultValue: DateTime.Now));

new DataColumn("myDate", typeof(DateTime));
```

This show ever the same error. I do not have idea to resolve this, any help me please?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried

```
Sql("alter table dbo.Dispositivoes alter column RegisterDate datetime2 not null default getdate()")
```

or

```
AlterColumn("dbo.Dispositivoes", "RegisterDate", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false, storeType: "datetime2", defaultValueSql: "GETDATE()"));
```